# Python Regex - replace a string not located between two specific words

Tags: python, regex

Given a string, I need to replace a substring with another in an area **not** located between two given words.

For example:

```
substring: "ate" replace to "drank", 1st word - "wolf", 2nd word - "chicken"

input:  The wolf ate the chicken and ate the rooster
output: The wolf ate the chicken and drank the rooster
```

Currently, the only solution I have is extremely unclean:

1) Replace the string located between the two words to a temporary substring, via [Replace a string located between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096720/replace-a-string-located-between)

2) replace the string I originally wanted

3) revert the temporary string to the original string

Edit:

I specifically asked a slightly different question than my case to keep the answer relevant for future readers.

My specific need is splitting a string according to ":", when I need to disregard ":" that are between "<" and ">" brackets that can be chained, where the only promise is that the number of opening brackets equal the number of closing brackets.

So for example, In the following case:

```
input  a : <<a : b> c> : <a < a < b : b> : b> : b> : a
output [a, <<a : b> c>, <a < a < b : b> : b> : b>, a]
```

If the answers are very different, I'll start another question.

Comment: wolf: `{`, chicken: `}`, ate:`a`. Are any of these possible: `"a { a a } a"`, `"a {a} a {a} a"`, `"{a {a} }"`, `"{a} a a"`? Can you edit the question to explain some more cases?

Comment: yes, especially {a {a} }, in which case none of these "a" should be changed.

Comment: In Python, are you using `re` or `regex`? Have you considered a non-regex solution?

Comment: re, python 2.7, but same applies for 3.4

Comment: With all the cases in my comment (and more), I'd take a risk and say you cannot do it with a Python `re` regex. With the `regex` module you have recursion (IIRC), but I'm not sure you want to go there either. Write a loop, count `{` and `}`, and replace when `count` is `0`.

Comment: Also, please edit the question: the example is confusing, and you should mention more interesting cases.

Comment: Are you certain that the constraint you have come up with ("occurrence of word not between two other words") is necessarily the best one? Perhaps another constraint might lead to a more tenable solution - in the quoted example, "last occurrence of a word in a line" would be one such alternative, but I don't know if that's suitable for your real use case... Sometimes redefining the problem at hand can get you out of what seems like a difficult solution...

Comment: I specifically asked a slightly different question than my case to keep the answer relevant for future readers. My specific need is splitting a string according to ":", when I need to disregard ":" that are between "<" and ">" brackets that can be chained, where the only promise is that the number of opening brackets equal the number of closing brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub` one-liner function.

```
>>> s = "The wolf ate the chicken and ate the rooster"
>>> re.sub(r'wolf.*?chicken|\bate\b', lambda m: "drank" if m.group()=="ate" else m.group(), s)
'The wolf ate the chicken and drank the rooster'
```

**Update:**

Updated problem would be solved by using `regex` module.

```
>>> s = "a : <<a : b> c> : <a < a < b : b> : b> : b> : a"
>>> [i for i in regex.split(r'(<(?:(?R)|[^<>])*>)|\s*:\s*', s) if i]
['a', '<<a : b> c>', '<a < a < b : b> : b> : b>', 'a']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hX4lM0/4)

Comment: The DEMO link isn't working properly, the attached python example works perfectly.

Comment: yep, it shows only  the captured text. Added just to show how nested `<>` are captured.

Comment: I did find a problem: a< b <c a>> (no ":" )is being split into ['a', '< b <c a>>']. I don't want to pre-optimize, but I have no idea what's the performance relative to a tailored non-regex solution.

Comment: if you have any further problems, please ask it as a new question along with the sample input and expected output.

Comment: asked a follow up question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727339/python-regex-splitting-according-to-criteria

Answer (score 3):

```
def repl(match):
    if match.group()=="ate":
        return "drank"
    return  match.group()


x="The wolf ate the chicken and ate the rooster"
print re.sub(r"(wolf.*chicken)|\bate\b",repl,x)
```

You can use a function for replacement to do the trick with `re.sub`

Comment: This is what I meant :)