# python regex splitting according to criteria

Tags: python, regex

A follow up on question [Python Regex - replace a string not located between two specific words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29675262/python-regex-replace-a-string-not-located-between-two-specific-words)
as the answers were incomplete.

Given a string str, split according to "::", while disregarding "::" that are between "<" and ">" brackets.

Expected inputs and outputs:

```
input  a :: <<a :: b> c>::<a < a < b:: b> :: b> :: b> ::      a
output [a , <<a :: b> c>,<a < a < b:: b> :: b> :: b> ,      a]

input a< b <c a>>
output [a< b <c a>>]

input a:<a b>
output [a:<a b>]
```

Comment: There's an answer in the link, what's the problem?

Comment: `[i for i in regex.split(r'(<(?:(?R)|[^<>])*>)|\s?::\s?', s) if i]` will work.

Comment: The answer is incomplete, as  a< b <c a>> (no ":" )is being split into ['a', '< b <c a>>']. I'll remove the check sign from the accepted answer.

Comment: @ErezO which input string you used?

Comment: s = "a< b <c a>>", res = [i for i in regex.split(r'(<(?:(?R)|[^<>])*>)|\s?::\s?', s) if i], res = ['a', '< b <c a>>']. Basically, the 2nd input isn't working.

Comment: So, what's the expected output for the above?

Comment: No "::", so no split. In both the 2nd and 3rd example, there should be no split as there's no "::". Regex-2015.3.18 if it makes a difference

Comment: @ErezO in the previous question, you made many number of edits. So we come up with a solution according to the expected output you provided. It works for that specific input. Now you ask for not to split if there is no `:` symbol present in the input. So this question is good here. But accept a solution which closely solves your previous problem.

Comment: I agree, I'll recheck the previous question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75624/discussion-between-erezo-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an if else condition is needed for this case. This would do splitting if there is any `::` substring present inside the input string else it would return the actual input string.

```
>>> def csplit(s):
        if '::' in s:
            return [i for i in regex.split(r'(<(?:(?R)|[^<>])*>)|::', s) if i and i != ' ']
        else:
            return s


>>> csplit('a :: <<a :: b> c>::<a < a < b:: b> :: b> :: b> ::      a')
['a ', '<<a :: b> c>', '<a < a < b:: b> :: b> :: b>', '      a']
>>> csplit('a:<a b>')
'a:<a b>'
>>> csplit('a< b <c a>>')
'a< b <c a>>'
```