# Remove String between two characters for all occurrences

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

I am looking for help on string manipulation in Python 3.

**Input String**

```
s = "ID bigint,FIRST_NM string,LAST_NM string,FILLER1 string"
```

**Desired Output**

```
s = "ID,FIRST_NM,LAST_NM,FILLER1"
```

Basically, the objective is to remove anything between space and comma at all occurrences in the input string.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace a string located between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096720/replace-a-string-located-between)

Comment: ``",".join(x.split()[0] for x in s.split(","))`` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using simple `regex`

```
import re
s = "ID bigint,FIRST_NM string,LAST_NM string,FILLER1 string"
res = re.sub('\s\w+', '', s)
print(res) 

# output ID,FIRST_NM,LAST_NM,FILLER1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex

```
import re

s = "ID bigint,FIRST_NM string,LAST_NM string,FILLER1 string"
s = ','.join(re.findall('\w+(?= \w+)', s))
print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
ID,FIRST_NM,LAST_NM,FILLER1
```