# Replace text inside bracket with an anchor link

Tags: python

I currently have a body of text as such

```
text = "hello this [is a cool] line of text that might have [two] brackets.
```

What I need is to parse, and replace this text, so in this example it would end up like

```
text = "hello this <a href='/phrase/is a cool/'>is a cool</a> line of text that might have <a href='/phrase/two/'>two</a> brackets.
```

Now I think in regex to find everything brackets is `\[.*?\]`, but I'm unsure how to do this specifically.

Comment: Can you user `{}` instead of `[]`?

Comment: @Jortega I suppose

Comment: Ok now we can use `.format` and save a lot of effort.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096720/replace-a-string-located-between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```py
import re

text = "hello this [is a cool] line of text that might have [two] brackets."

brackets = re.compile(r'\[(.*?)\]')
new_text = brackets.sub(lambda x: f'<a href=/phrases/{x.group(1)}>{x.group(1)}</a>', text)

print(new_text)
```

This will replace the pattern with what the lambda returns:
`x.group(1)` returns the first group in the regex pattern (indexing starts from 1): `(.*?)`, meaning it will return only the text in between brackets and then format it using `f strings`.

To also remove any punctuation from the text in the brackets this code could be used (notice how the end result doesn't have any of the `.` that were in between the brackets):

```py
import re
import string

text = "hello this [is a..... cool] line of text that might have [two] brackets."


def replace_with_link(match):
    info = match.group(1)
    info = info.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
    return f'<a href="/phrases/{info}">{info}</a>'


brackets = re.compile(r'\[(.*?)\]')
new_text = brackets.sub(replace_with_link, text)

print(new_text)
```

Comment: Thank you, I suppose if inside the brackets they have special charectors like commas or periods, this will leave them in or strip them? and if so, any way to strip them?

Comment: @nadermx well `.` matches any character (except newline) and doesn't really exclude anything, I will edit to add how to remove all the punctuation if that is what you were looking for

Comment: @nadermx I had added the code for punctuation, I am pretty sure that I wrote a comment saying that but now I don't see it so just in case I wrote this one

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by following

1. Get all substrings enclosed by `[` and `]`
2. Replace the content with appropriate text

```py
>>> import re
>>> txt = "hello this [is a cool] line of text that might have [two] brackets."
>>> phrases = re.findall(r"(\[.+?\])", txt)
>>> for phrase in phrases:
...     txt = txt.replace(phrase, "<a href='/phrase/{}/'>{}</a>".format(phrase[1:-1], phrase[1:-1]))
... 
>>> txt
"hello this <a href='/phrase/is a cool/'>is a cool</a> line of text that might have <a href='/phrase/two/'>two</a> brackets."
>>>
```